# Using Async Event Listener with Nestjs EventEmitter Module and Serverless functions

Tags: javascript, nestjs, serverless-framework, eventemitter

I'm trying to implement an asynchronous worker with serverless lambda function with help of nestjs EventEmitter module.

Handler is getting invoked on emitting an event, but the function gets closed before the async / await call.

I have tried using both `emit` and `emitAsync` functions and different arguments for
`@OnEvent(AccountEvents.NEW_ACCOUNT, {async:true, promisify:true})`

Producer Snippet

```
  public async execute(event: EventDetail): Promise<void> {

    await this.eventEmitter.emitAsync(AccountEvents.NEW_ACCOUNT, event);
  }
```

Listener Snippet

```
@OnEvent(AccountEvents.NEW_ACCOUNT)
  public async handleAccountCreatedEvent(event: EventDetail): Promise<void> {
    this.logger.log({ message: `Log1: ${AccountEvents.NEW_ACCOUNT} Handler`, event });
    const message = await this.testAsync();
    this.logger.log({ message });
    this.logger.log({ message: 'Log 3: Event Processing Successfuly Completed' });
  }

  private testAsync(): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise(res => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        res('Log 2: Promise resolved after one sec');
      }, 1000);
    });
  }
```

Expect Output : all the 3 log statements
Actual Output : only first log statement (Log1)

Answer (score 5):

Making Changes as follows works. Basically we need pass `{ async: true, promisify: true }` to the annotation `@onEvent`.

```
 @OnEvent(AccountEvents.NEW_ACCOUNT, { async: true, promisify: true })
  async handleNewAccountEvent(event: IEvent<RootAccountInterface>): Promise<void> {
    const eventDetail: RootAccountInterface = event.data;
    this.logger.log({ message: ` ${AccountEvents.NEW_ACCOUNT} Handler`, event });
    await this.abc.logNewAccountCreation(eventDetail.accountId);

    this.logger.log({ message: ` ${AccountEvents.NEW_ACCOUNT} Handled Successfully`, event });
  }
```